# Proving $\forall x\in\mathbb R : \dfrac{e^x + e^{-x}}2 \le e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ with Cauchy's MVT

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

> Prove for all $x\in\mathbb R$:
>   $$\dfrac{e^x + e^{-x}}2 \le e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$

Mclauren expansion:

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+R_4(x)$$

$$e^{-x}=1+-x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3!}+S_4(x)$$

Adding both together: $2+\frac{x^2}{2}+R_4(x)+S_4(x)$

**Question:** Can I cancel $R_4(x)+S_4(x)$ because they tend to $0$ ? if yes then this is how I continued:

We have now: $2+\dfrac{x^2}2 \le e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$, or $\dfrac{2+\dfrac{x^2}2}{e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}} \le 1$.

Now I thought about using Cauchy's MVT here: define: $f(x)=2+\dfrac{x^2}2 , \ g(x)= e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ both are continous and differentiable on all $\mathbb R$ so:

$$\frac {f(x)} {g(x)}=\frac {f'(x)-f'(0)}{g'(x)-g'(0)}=\frac{1}{e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}}\le1$$

This is related to: [Proving that $\frac{e^x + e^{-x}}2 \le e^{x^2/2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654839/proving-that-fracex-e-x2-le-ex2-2) but my approach is different and I want to know if it's correct.

Note: I can't use integration.

Comment: $e^x = 1 + x/1! + x^2/2! + \cdots$

Comment: @S.B. oh right! it doesn't change much here though because they cancel out.

Comment: $e^{-x} = 1 - x/1! + x^2/2! +\cdots$

Comment: You are eliminating a non-negative term (i.e., $R_4(x) + S_4(x)$) from the left hand side of the desired inequality. Therefore, what you prove is weaker than what you actually want.

Comment: @S.B. I asked if it's allowed to cancel the remainders since they tend to 0 (Peano's remainder).

Comment: You want to prove $A + B \leq C$, where $B\geq 0$. It's not sufficient to prove $A \leq C$.

Comment: @S.B. so in general it's not allowed to cancel out remainders, especially outside of limits ?

Comment: You're asking whether, if $f(x)=g(x)+r(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a} r(x)=0$, we can conclude $f(x)=g(x)$.  The answer is no.  But I also worry that this answer will not be of much use to you, because to ask the question in the first place suggests some underlying misunderstanding which the bare answer cannot address.  Why did it seem possible that the answer could be yes?

Comment: @StevenTaschuk because they can be canceled out when calculating a limit and substituting a function with it's Taylor polynomial, I probably thought the same can be done when not calculating limits. Thanks for clearing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} & = 1+\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \frac{x^6}{720} + \frac{x^8}{40230} + \cdots \\[12pt]
e^{x^2/2} & = 1 + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{8} + \frac{x^6}{48} + \frac{x^8}{384} + \cdots
\end{align}

If you can show that the denominators must remain smaller in the second series than in the first, that does it.
$$
(2n)! > n! 2^n \text{ for }n\ge 2 \text{ ?}
$$
That should be provable by induction.  In the sequence $\{(2n)!\}_{n=0,1,2,3,\ldots}$, when $n$ is incremented to $n+1$, one multiplies by $(2n+1)(2n+2)$.  In the sequence $\{n!2^n\}_{n=0,1,2,3,\ldots}$, one multiplies by $2(n+1)$.  In the induction step, all you need is that $2(n+1)<(2n+1)(2n+2)$ for $n\ge 2$.

**PS:** If you add your two Maclaurin series, you get $2+x^2 + R_4(x)+S_4(x)$. (You have $x^2/2$ where you need $x^2$.)  The ratios of $R_4(x)$ and $S_4(x)$ to $x^3$ both approach $0$ as $x\to0$.  From that it follows that the ratio of their sum to $x^3$ also approaches $0$.  That doesn't say whether their sum is positive, negative, or $0$.

You say "We now have $\text{[something]}\le e^{x^2/2}$".  That is not correct.  "We now have" normally means "We have now proved".  This isn't something you've proved; it's something it would now suffice to prove (if what preceded it had been correct).

In your proposed application of Cauchy's mean value theorem, you have the roles of $f$ and $f'$ incorrectly interchanged.  You also seem to be using $x$ to refer to two different things.  You need to look closely at what the theorem says before you try to apply it.

The question is really about what comes *after* the second-degree terms in the power series.  If you look at the difference
$$
e^{x^2/2} - \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2},
$$
you would expand it as a power series in which the first non-zero term is a fourth-degree term.  You need to show that that is always positive.

Comment: (Alternatively, $(2n)!/n! = \prod_{k=n+1}^{2n} k > \prod_{k=n+1}^{2n} 2 = 2^n$ if $n\ge2$.)

Comment: Thanks for all the corrections. I didn't know that about the formality of "we now have". I see that I did mix up the functions in the MVT but about the $x$ and $c\in(a,b)$, if $a=-\infty, \ b=\infty$ then in this case: $x=c$ no ?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach:
$$ \ln\cosh x = \int_0^x \tanh t\,dt \le \int_0^x t\,dt = \frac{x^2}{2} $$
This uses the fact that $\tanh x\le x$ for $x\ge 0$ (and the reverse for $x\le 0$), which can be proved by computing the second derivative of $\tanh$, concluding that it's convex on $(\infty,0]$ and concave on $[0,\infty)$, and comparing it to its tangent line at $x=0$.  Another way is to use the fact that if $f$ is convex on $[a,b]$ then
$$ \frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)\,dx
= \int_0^1 f((1-t)a+tb) \,dt
\le \int_0^1 \big((1-t)f(a)+tf(b)\big)\,dt
= \frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2} $$
Applying this to $f(x)=e^x$ on $[-u,u]$ yields $\frac{\sinh u}{u}\le\cosh u$, which gives the needed inequalities for $\tanh$.

**Edit.**  You've added a note to the question saying that you can't use integration.  The first line of this answer can be reformulated to accommodate that restriction: prove that if $f(a)\le g(a)$ and $f'(x)\le g'(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$, then $f(x)\le g(x)$ for all $x\in[a,b]$ (this is a consequence of MVT); then take $f(x)=\ln\cosh x$ and $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$.