# An inequality about exponentials.

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, exponentiation

I have 2 questions,

- Is the following inequality true? If yes why? 
  $$\frac{1}{2} \times ( e^{x} + e^{-x} ) \leq e^{\frac {x^2}{2}}   $$
- In general for real numbers $a, b$ do we have a nice upperbound like above on, 
  $$\frac{1}{2} \times ( ae^{x} + be^{-x} )$$

---

Feel free to assume $a, b >0$ if needed.

Comment: Your first question is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654839/proving-that-fracex-e-x2-le-ex2-2). I think that your second question can be answered through looking at existing [similar answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cleq+e%5E%7B%5Cfrac+%7Bx%5E2%7D%7B2%7D%7D).

Comment: Now that I have done more work on scratch paper, I couldn't find a nice upper bound on the second question that worked for all $a,b>0$ (that wasn't something uninteresting like $ae^x+be^{-x}$). It would be nice to see if the upper bound looks similar to the first one.

Comment: Using the first result you get an upper bound for the second by $\max\{\vert a\vert, \vert b\vert\} \exp(x^2/2)$.

Comment: That essentially weakens the inequality...

Answer (score 0):

$\cosh(x)\leq e^{x^2/2}$ is equivalent to $\log\cosh(x)\leq \frac{x^2}{2}$. We may safely assume $x>0$ since both sides are even.
Since $\tanh(x)\leq x$ for any $x>0$ (this is a convexity inequality) we have
$$ \log\cosh(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\tanh(t)\,dt\leq \int_{0}^{x}t\,dt = \frac{x^2}{2} $$
and the first inequality is proved. Assuming that for some $a,b>0$ the inequality $2e^{x^2/2}\geq ae^x+be^{-x}$ holds, by mapping $x$ into $-x$ we have that $2e^{x^2/2}\geq be^x+ae^{-x}$ also holds, so by letting $c=\max(a,b)$ we are asking for the optimal constant $c$ such that $e^{x^2/2}\geq c\cosh(x)$ holds. This constant can be found through
$$ \frac{1}{c}=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \cosh(x)e^{-x^2}, $$
but $f(x)=\cosh(x)e^{-x^2}$ is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, so the optimal constant is just $c=1$. Indeed
$$ \log f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\left(\tanh(t)-t\right)\,dt $$
is negative and decreasing.

Comment: I don't understand what you are claiming here. Suppose we look for an upper bound $c\exp(dx^2)$. Any inequality of this type is hopeless for large $x$. If you are only interested in small $x$, then looking at the Taylor series it is obvious that $a=b=d=0.5,c=1$ is essentially the only way to get $O(x^4)$ (and with a little more effort that that inequality is valid). But if you are interested in the best over a neighbourhood of 0, then you can do better, eg  If you take $a=b=0.5,c=1.03,d=0.41$, gives a maximum difference between the two sides of 0.03 over the interval $x\in[-1,1]$.

Comment: @almagest: of course, but I guess the OP was interested in a global bound, not just a bound in a neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: Maybe! But to me the only interesting thing about the original inequality is how good it is close to the origin. Both the original and the desired variants (different $a,b$) are obviously useless for large $x$. So I assumed he was interested in what you could do for $a\ne b$ for $x$ "not too large". To which the answer is messy - there is nothing approaching the elegance of the original.